# SVG background repeat in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, css, background-repeat

I've got a repeating stripe pattern which I've made as an SVG. I've then optimised it and exported it as a Data URI and applied as a repeating background in CSS.

Works nicely in FireFox & Chrome and also have control over background-size which makes the stripes nice and fluid.

Now, tested in IE. No repeating SVG???  Does IE support repeating SVGs?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the version of IE that you're using. [Prior to IE 9, there was no support for SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics#Support_for_SVG_in_web_browsers). You would need a plugin to render SVG content. IF it's IE 9 or higher, displaying repeating SVGs should not be a problem.

Comment: I've done a a little test and it suggests that repeating SVG's don't work.

Comment: Maybe its because its a DATA URI but it aint working in IE10.

Comment: If it's still not working, I'd suggest just falling back on a rasterized SVG of the whole repeating pattern for IE.